# Appending HDFStore pandas TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46206376/11578009 I am trying to append HDFStore file

```
import pandas as pd
hdfStore = pd.HDFStore('dataframe.h5')

#df=
#a              b               c                       d   f
#0             125           -6.450  ...                0  2020-04-#16T02:30:00
#2             124           -6.403  ...                0  2020-04-#16T02:30:00
#4             128           -6.403  ...                0  2020-04-#16T02:30:00
#
#[3 rows x 5 columns]

hdfStore.append('df', df,  format='t',data_columns=True )
```

Trying to append this df to hdfStore throws:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out answer when I was replicating error, but maybe it will be useful for sb.

Error does not occur when dtypes in used pd.DataFrame are

```
df.dtypes
Out[65]: 
time_diffrences     int64
temp_diffrences     int64
label              object
dtype: object
```

So dtypes cant be for example 'object' for integer