# PANDAS: Appending h5, one key is a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, h5py

Take the following example data:

```
tag = [123,124,125]
rad = [[40.0, 33.0, 23.2], [22.3, 11.6, 20.3], [45.2, 96.2, 77.3]]
```

I made a pandas dataframe with `tag` and `rad` as the keys, where `df['rad'][0]=[40.0, 33.0, 23.2]`. I need each row value in `rad` to remain a list.

Now, I'm trying to append this data to an existing dataframe:

```
store_radial = pd.HDFStore('radials.h5')
df = pd.DataFrame('tag':tag,'radial':[rad]})
store_radial.put('tag', df, append=True, format='t', data_columns=True)
```

I've seen this method work in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206125/append-data-to-hdf5-file-with-pandas-python) here, but when I run it using my data, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [radial] because
its data contents are [mixed] object type
```

The types are the following:

```
radial    object
tag        int64
dtype: object
```

I believe my issue is caused by `rad` being a list. Is there a way to append to a `.h5` file while keeping `rad` as a list? If there is a better way to do this, I'm all ears. Please let me know if I need to clarify.

---

Update:
I have also tried the following and still get the same error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'radials':[rad_pro], 'tag':tag})
df['radials'].to_hdf('r%d_radials.h5' % run, key='radials', mode='a', append=True, format='table')
```

From what I understand, the dtype of `rad` needs to match what the individual values in the list are for this to work. The error is saying that inside `radials`, the dtypes are mixed. Which I don't quite understand why that is.

Clarification update:
To clarify further, I want my dataframe to look like this:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
              radials    tag
0  [40.0, 33.0, 23.2]    123
1  [22.3, 11.6, 20.3]    124
2  [45.2, 96.2, 77.3]    125
```

From there, I want the appended `.h5` to keep the format above, where `df['radials'][i]` is a list.

Comment: You should not use h5 for a column of lists. Suggest you break radials into multiple columns or rows. See `pd.DataFrame.explode()`

Comment: @Kyle, I need to keep the columns of lists as they are. I do not necessarily need to use h5 format for this, but I do need to save and append the data to a larger file.

Comment: don't know much about h5, but what if you convert your radials column to a string: df['radials'].astype(str) and then append it to your file. And when you read in the file again, you convert the column that is a string back to a list again with: df['radials'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',')

Comment: @SandervandenOord, I tried that. The arrays are too long.