# Will Pandas auto sort new data appended to a dataframe (in hdf5 format)

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

For example, I got a df1, index from 20200101 to 20210101, dtype is DateTime, and I already save this df to h5 (format is table).
Then I got a new df2, index from 20200101 to 20200201, which is in the middle of the index of df1.
If I append df2 to this h5, will it auto sort index?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the existing workflow. Do you have a simple example to share? (Likely writing the example will answer your question.) In regards to HDF5, it doesn't have any auto-sort capabilities. Pandas might be able to sort a dataframe. You would have to merge df1 and df2 and save the merged, sorted df as a new key (dataset) in HDF5.

Comment: Review this SO Q&A. [Append data to HDF5 file with Pandas, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46206125/10462884). The last sentence of the second answer addresses your question: "_HDF5 won't do anything with the dataframe's indexes. We need to iron those out before putting the data in or when we take it out._"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy enough to write an example to demonstrate the behavior and the solution.

Code below creates 2 dataframes of odd and even numbers and writes them to an HDF5 file  in Table format as `key='test_data'`. (Table format required to append data.) When you run that, you will see that the odd numbers are first, followed by the even numbers (NOT auto-sorted).

```
col2 = [ x for x in range(1,53,2)]
col3 = [ float(x) for x in range(1,53,2)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_int': col2, 'col_float': col3})
df1.to_hdf('SO_70731279.h5',key='test_data',mode='w', format='table',
           data_columns=True)

col2 = [ x for x in range(2,54,2)]
col3 = [ float(x) for x in range(2,54,2)]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_int': col2, 'col_float': col3})
df2.to_hdf('SO_70731279.h5',key='test_data',mode='a', format='table',
           data_columns=True, append=True)
```

This code reads the data from `key='test_data'` to df3, sorts the dataframe in-place, then writes to the HDF5 file with `key='sorted_data'`. Run this and you will see this data in the HDF5 file is in ascending order.

```
df3 = pd.read_hdf('SO_70731279.h5',key='test_data',columns=['col_int','col_float'])
df3.sort_values('col_int',inplace=True,ignore_index=True)
df3.to_hdf('SO_70731279.h5',key='sorted_data',mode='a', format='table',
           data_columns=True)
```

If you want to REPLACE the data in `key='test_data'`, you have to write df3 to the key and not include `append=True`. This will overwrite the key.

```
df3.to_hdf('SO_70731279.h5',key='test_data',mode='a', format='table',
           data_columns=True)  ## Note append=True is missing on this call
```

This solution will solve your problem. However, computational efficiency with very large dataframes is unknown. You should test with your data before implementing. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see. Appending to h5 would not auto-sort index. Yes, as you mentioned, it would take a lot of time to read to df, sort using pandas dataframe, re-write into h5, if the database is big.